FS2 who to do a onCancelWith
I have a grpc service which ofer an API looking like that def f(input: fs2.Stream[F, Input]) : fs2.Stream[F, Output]
the Input is basically formed like
sealed trait Input
case Data(x : ByteBuffer) extends Input
case EndOfInput extends Input
case Cancel extends Input

The idea is to have a Stream[F,ByteBuffer] that are then converted into a Stream[F,Input].

In case of completion add a EndOfInput.
In case of output stream interuption I would like to stop sending Data but add a last Cancel.
In case of Error I think I could also send a Cancel, but since Ouput  also contain Error element which are then raised as exception into Stream I a bit afraid that we will trie to send a Cancel to the third party service when he send an error.

Idealy I could have a .finalize that look like
// Output the last elements before termination
def latelyCase[F2[x] >: F[x]]( 
    f: ExitCase[Throwable] => Stream[F2,O]
) : Stream[F2,O]


The issue is I find no way to put a last cancel element in the input stream when it is cancel as .onComplete would do. It anoying because sometime I want to be able to interup the output stream (resulting in the interuption of the input stream)
I tried solution with mergeHaltBoth combine by a Deferred completed in the onFinalize of the input stream, but the Finalize of the Deferred is cancel before the execution of the completed and I find no why to make a stream uninterruptible.

Sorry, not sure I understand what is the question problem? Are you having trouble sending the Cancel element? You don't know how to stop the output Stream once the Cancel element is received? - Oh, I think I understand now, you need to guarantee the input Stream sends a Cancel no matter what?

I will try to rephrase everything, especially this morning I woke up with another idea.


"Are you having trouble sending the Cancel element? "
yes exaclty , > " you need to guarantee the input Stream sends a Cancel no matter what?" not exactly, only when the stream in interupted before completion.

